# How to automatically start programs in specific workspaces on start up

Tags: startup, workspaces

I would like to add a command at the rc.d system by which, when ubuntu starts it will run different program at different workspaces.I.e:workspace 1: chrome,workspace 2:thunderbird.How could this be achieved?Is there any tool?

Answer (score 3):

even though you could actually write some script to auto-start any application you want in different X sessions, you may want to have a look at the confgiuration files of your wm (which is?).

to do exactly what you asked, eg, with xmonad (my wm) you simply have to write a few lines, like

```
className =? "Icedove"             --> doShift "3:mail"
```

if you use compiz, i think there's a plugin to put an application in a specific workspace. so all you have to do is simply to auto-start them.

so please specify your wm :)

Comment: home@home-Aspire-1810TZ:/etc/init.d$ wmctrl -m
Name: Compiz
Class: N/A
PID: N/A

Comment: i've found that devilspie is the tool that i am searching for.I'll let you know.I also found compizconfig-settings-manager but i prefer sth from command line

Comment: It seems that under Compiz wm, devilspie commands are not working.I create a simple user.ds file under ~user/.devilspies 

`(if 
  (is (application_name) "google-chrome") 
  (set_workspace 2)
)`
but it seems that it doesn't follow the rule.