# How to start application in other workspaces?

Tags: 10.04, startup, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automatically start programs in specific workspaces on start up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50467/how-to-automatically-start-programs-in-specific-workspaces-on-start-up)

When I login how do I start an application to open on other workspaces!

for example...

- System Starting....
- Workspace1 -->Open Firefox ...
- Workspace2 -->Open Terminal ....
- Workspace3 -->Open Movie ...etc.

Comment: thank you very much...I do not devilspies folder.. I have Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: firstly add the software you want on startup. Then look the second answer here on how to determine software->workspace  http://askubuntu.com/questions/87002/how-can-i-get-a-startup-application-to-run-in-another-workspace-other-than-1.